# Setting values to each comboBox item

Tags: codenameone

populate combobox code:

```
ComboBox getCategoryComboBox = new ComboBox();
searchOptionForm.add(getCategoryComboBox);

getCategoryComboBox.setUIID("TextField");
getCategoryComboBox.addItem("Choose Category");

for (Map<String, Object> entry : alacc.responseCategory) {
    String categoryName = (String) entry.get("name");
    String categoryId = (String) entry.get("id");//how to set this to combobox item
    getCategoryComboBox.addItem(categoryName);
}
```

categoryId is taken from for loop above, how to set it in each combobox items? I need to get the categoryId of each selected combobox item, how can i get this?

Answer (score 0):

You have several ways to do this.

One way is to just do:

```
getCategoryComboBox.addItem(entry);
```

Which would provide you the full entry on `getSelectedItem()` effectively solving that problem.

To make the name render properly though you would need to do this:

```
cb.setRenderer(new DefaultListCellRenderer<Object>() {
   public Component getCellRendererComponent(Component list, Object model, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected) {
      if(value instanceof Map) {
         value = ((Map)value).get("name");
      }
      return super.getCellRendererComponent(list, model, value, index, isSelected);
   }
});
```

Notice you will also need to define the theme constant `otherPopupRendererBool` to false for this to work properly.

Comment: I want to show the categoryName only in combobox list but when one of them is selected, I need to get the categoryId of selected option . How can I get the selected categoryId. thankyou

Comment: That is explained above. The item value would be the map, but you will only see the name because of the renderer